# Return string between single quote with awk

Tags: shell, awk

I'm currently writing a script to mass reset wordpress username and passwords. The passwords were stored using old-passwords and now with an update to MySQL and PHP, the old passwords are no longer working and hence need to be reset.

I have a file that looks like this:

```
define('DB_USER', 'abc_12345');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'abc12345');
define('DB_USER', 'def_34589');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'def34589');
```

I'm just needing to return the values inside the single quotes:

```
DB_USER abc_12345
DB_PASSWORD abc12345

DB_USER def_34589
DB_PASSWORD def34589
```

Now, I've looked around at the similar questions, but they all are a bit different then what I'm working with.

I've tried the following:

```
cat file.txt | awk '{print $1,$2}'
```

which returns

```
define('DB_USER', 'abc_12345');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'abc12345');
define('DB_USER', 'def_34589');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'def34589');
```

I've tried

```
cat file.txt | awk '{print $1}'
```

which returns

```
define('DB_USER',
define('DB_PASSWORD',
```

I've tried

```
cat file.txt | awk '{print $2}'
```

which returns

```
'abc_12345');
'abc12345');
```

I've also tried awk mixed with grep

```
cat file.txt | awk '{print $2}' | grep -P " '*.' "
```

which doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
awk -F\' '{print $2,$4}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the record separator flag `-F` of `awk` and separate at `'`

```
$> string="define('DB_USER', 'abc_12345');"
$> echo $string | awk -F"'" '{print $2}'
DB_USER
$> echo $string | awk -F"'" '{print $4}'
abc_12345
```

Or just simply pass the file

```
awk -F"'" '{print $2 $4}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `GNU grep`:

```
$ grep -Po "(?<=')[^',]+(?=')" file | xargs -n2
DB_USER abc_12345
DB_PASSWORD abc12345
DB_USER def_34589
DB_PASSWORD def34589
```

This greps for anything inside single quotes that isn't a `'` or `,` then `xargs` just group the matches two per line.

**P.S never store passwords in plaintext!**

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just have one question, can you explain the "(?<=')[^',]+(?=')" portion? I've seen this but yet to full understand it.

Comment: It uses regular expression look arounds: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this in *Cygwin* the following way...

```
$ cat test.file | awk -F "\'" '{print $2" "$4}'
DB_USER abc_12345
```

You might get an *awk* warning because of the escapes, however the output should be exactly what you were wanting using similar syntax to what you already tried. I found that using double-quotes, at least in my shell, around a single-quote delimiter works well as long as you escape the single in the middle. For the output field of *awk* however you want to switch back to the single-quotes, otherwise you will have errors like this...

```
$ cat test.file | awk -F "\'" "{print $2" "$4}"
awk: cmd. line:1: {print
awk: cmd. line:1:        ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

As an aside, I understand using *cat* is not as efficient as *awk* by itself, but very often I build one liners like this using cat, trimming output up as I go. If I were to script this out, I would consider a more efficient method, but if I'm generating a one-time report, it makes no difference to me.